# Как получить данные с react формы?

Tags: reactjs

Привет не могу получить данные с формы на reactJs но сделал валидацию тперь не смог взять данные с формы и console.log()? Спасибо))

Это мой App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import './App.css'

function App() {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [emailDirty, setEmialDirty] = useState(false)
  const [passwordDirty, setPasswordDirty] = useState(false)
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('E-mail не может быть пустым!')
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState('Пароль не может быть пустым!')
  const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState(false)
  const [emailFind, passwordFind] = useState({email: '', password: ''})

  useEffect(() => {
     if(emailError || passwordError) {
        setFormValid(false)
     } else {
        setFormValid(true)
     }
  }, [emailError, passwordError])

  const emailHandler = (e) => {
      setEmail(e.target.value)
      const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      if(!re.test(String(e.target.value).toLowerCase())) {
          setEmailError('Некорректный E-mail!')
          if(!e.target.value) {
              setEmailError('E-mail не может быть пустым!')
          }
      } else {
        setEmailError('')
      }
      console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  const passwordHandler = (e) => {
      setPassword(e.target.value)
      if(e.target.value.length < 6 || e.target.value.length > 8){
          setPasswordError('Пароль должен быть больше 6 или меньше 8')
          if(!e.target.value) {
              setPasswordError('Пароль не может быть пустым!')
          }
      } else {
        setPasswordError('')
      }
      console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  const blurHandler = (e) => {
    switch (e.target.name) {
      case 'email': 
        setEmialDirty(true)
        break
      case 'password': 
        setPasswordDirty(true)
        break
    }
  }


  return (
    <div className="app">
      <form>
        <h1>Регистрация</h1>
        {( emailDirty && emailError ) && <p style={{color: "red"}}>{ emailError }</p>}
        <input 
            value={email} 
            onChange={e => emailHandler(e)}
            onBlur={e => blurHandler(e)} 
            name="email" type="text" 
            placeholder="E-mail" 
            /> <br/>
        {( passwordDirty && passwordError ) && <p style={{color: "red"}}>{ passwordError }</p>}
        <input 
            value={password} 
            onChange={e => passwordHandler(e)}
            onBlur={e => blurHandler(e)} 
            name="password" 
            type="password" 
            placeholder="Пароль" 
            /><br/>
        <button disabled={!formValid} type="submit">Регистрация</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Что конкретно не смогли взять, куда смотреть?

Comment: Данные с input не смог вывести на console.log()

Comment: `console.log(e.target.value);` - тут?

Comment: Он не работает, не знаю почему.

Comment: @АлиНурлибеков все логи у вас работают. Но код ужасный.https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-thunder-t1n08

Comment: Можно это сделтаь так чтоб данные должен выйти при нажатии на button

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут я изменил свой код но почему не работает пароль! Когда начинаешь печатать на поле пароль выходит ошибка

```js
import React from 'react'

class App extends React.Component {
state = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
};

handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value })
}

handleChange2(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value })
}
  
handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state.email);
    console.log(this.state.password);
}
  
render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state
    return (
    <form>
    <label>
    <input type="text" value={email} name="email" placeholder="E-mail" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <input type="password" value={password} placeholder="Пароль" name="password" onChange={this.handleChange2} />
    </label>
    <input onClick={this.handleClick} type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
    );
}
}
  export default App
```